Why does this magma table satisfy $(w*x)*(y*z) = w*z$?
Here's a simple binary operation $*$ on the set $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$:
$$
\begin{matrix}
* & | & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
0 & | & 0 & 3 & 0 & 3 \\ 
1 & | & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
2 & | & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
3 & | & 0 & 3 & 0 & 3 \\ 
\end{matrix}
$$
It seems to obey the relation $(w*x)*(y*z) = w*z$. I checked it with a program, but I'd still like to know: is there a short proof or other insight into why this is true?
Background: I ran into this while investigating monads in a category of types. The relation is related to monad associativity for the type constructor written in Haskell as $(a, a)$. I tried writing the operation as some kind of arithmetic calculation, without success. I notice that $*$ also obeys some other nice relations: $x*x = x$ ($*$ is idempotent); $x*1$ and $1*x \neq 0$; $x*0$ and $0*x \neq 1$. These also imply that $*$ is associative.

In fact it satisfies the stronger $xyz=xz$ (using the same proof as Arturo's). This is also a way to show associativity. I'm interested to learn if this property has a name! Or a name for an element $e$ that satisfies $xey=xy$

Can we change the question to: "how can we generate this magma from basic constructions and not from the table?"

@Milten, I would say "Middle-ignoring semigroup"? Which is the same thing as a rectangular band. Maybe some expert can confirm

@Mockingbird Thanks for the reference! I see that a band additionally requires idempotence which certainly is satisfied in the question but it’s slightly less general than just $xyz=xz$. But the distinction seems to be only up to some equivalence classes (see my answer). I will expand my answer later with this perspective.

Btw the law of this question appeared in Problem A4 of the 1978 Putnam exam.

(I am interpreting your table as saying that $a*b$ is the entry in the row labeled $a$ and the column labeled $b$; if you meant the entry in row labeled $b$ and column labeled $a$, swap the arguments accordingly)
Look at the first factors:  if $a\in\{0,3\}$ then so is $a*b$ for any $b$; and if $a\in\{1,2\}$ then so is $a*b$ for any $b$. Thus, $(w*x)*(y*z)$ is in the same "half" of $\{0,1,2,3\}$ as $w*x$, which is in the same as $w*z$: either both are in $\{0,3\}$, or both are in $\{1,2\}$.
Look at the second factors: the parity of $a*b$ always equals the parity of $b$: if $b\in\{0,2\}$, then so is $a*b$ for any $a$; and if $b\in\{1,3\}$, then so is $a*b$ for any $a$.
Putting the two together: $(w*x)*(y*z)$ has the same parity as $y*z$, which has the same parity as $w*z$. And they are both in $\{0,3\}$ or both in $\{1,2\}$; because each of these has only one element of each parity, it follows that $(w*x)*(y*z)$ must equal $w*z$.

More concisely, for $x,y\in{0,1}$, let $xy=-2x-y\bmod4$, so that $00=0$, $11=1$, $10=2$, $01=3$. Then $ab*cd=ad$ for $a,b,c,d\in{0,1}$.

Your operation is almost a generic case of an associative binary operation satisfying $x*y*z=x*z$ ("centrally absorbent" maybe?). The following is a general construction of such an operation on a set $S$:

Choose two partitions $S = \bigsqcup_{i\in I} S_i = \bigsqcup_{j\in J}T_j$ satisfying $S_i\cap T_j\ne\emptyset$ for all $i,j$.
For each pair $(i,j)$ choose an element $u_{ij}\in S_i\cap T_j$.
If $x\in S_i$ and $y\in T_j$, define $x*y=u_{ij}$. Or concisely, $S_i*T_j = \{u_{ij}\}$.

I'll probably sketch a proof for sufficiency and necessity later, but the main idea is that multiplication on the right/left preserves the $S$/$T$ set.
The $S$-sets are the fibers of right-multiplication by any fixed element, and similarly the $T$-sets are the fibers for left-multiplication.
In your case: $S_a = \{0,3\}$, $S_b = S_1 = \{1,2\}$, $T_a = \{0,2\}$, $T_b = \{1,3\}$, and $u_{aa}=0$, $u_{ab}=3$, $u_{ba}=2$, $u_{bb}=1$.
Relation to a few other properties:

If we add commutativity, it collapses to a constant operation ($xy=0$ for some fixed element $0$).
If there exists a left a right identity element, then the operation becomes $xy=y$ or $xy=x$ respectively. In the case of a two-sided identity the underlying set must be a singleton ($x = exe = e = eye = y$).
All elements satisfy $xxx=xx$, so there is a kind of generalized idempotence going on.


Represent the symbols $0,1,2,3$ by pairs of four different symbol strings $03,12,02,13$ in the following way:
\begin{array}\\
0=(03,02)\\
1=(12,13)\\
2=(12,02)\\
3=(03,13)\\
\end{array}
Now define $$(a,b)*(c,d)=(a,d)$$
You can check that this is isomorphic to the operation defined by the table.
Now you have
$$(w*x)*(y*z)=\\((w_1,w_2)*(x_1,x_2)) * ((y_1,y_2)*(z_1,z_2))=\\
(w_1,x_2)*(y_1,z_2)=\\(w_1,z_2)$$
And you also have
$$w*z=(w_1,w_2)*(z_1,z_2)=(w_1,z_2)$$
